# Pass a object of values from client to parent in angular when loaded

Tags: angular, parent-child

I need to pass a group of values to the parent when a child component is loaded.   Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the "data class"

[image]

parent.component.ts contains this function:

[image]

and child.component.ts looks like this:

[image]

*** UPDATE ***
I should probably mention that the child pages are being loaded by a router action from the menu for a Single Page Application:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text, just copy paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the child components are being loaded dynamically using a routerlink,  the "router-output" tag does support emit since the page has not yet loaded.  The solution was to create a mediator service follow the instructions I found at the link below.

Thank you everyone for you help.
 
https://chinedujude.medium.com/angular-emit-event-through-router-outlet-53b55fbd1f28

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot call emit in the body of the class. You need to call  it inside a method or lifecycle. So in your case most likely what would work is

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.updateParent.emit(dbButtons)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your templates look like but:

1. call `this.updateParentEmit(...)` inside a method od the class or inside the template (`updateParentEmit(...)`)
2. if you run it inside a `ngOnInit` lifecycle method (for emitting the initial value) you might need to move it to the event loop queue if you set the change detection strategy to `OnPush`
3. If you need the inivial value (that does not come from the UI interaction event) it is way better to utilize `BehaviorSubject` as the emitter
4. it is highly recommended to use `OnPush` strategy - like PRO does :)

Here you have en example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-b8ubnj)

And some snippets of the code:

**Parent TS**:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ParentComponent {
  protected value: number = -1;

  eventOneAction(event: number) {
    this.value = event;
  }
}
```

**Parent HTML**:

```
<h3>Parent: {{ value }}</h3>
<app-child (eventOne)="eventOneAction($event)"></app-child>
```

**Child TS**:

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  OnInit,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';
import { asapScheduler, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  protected initialValue = 3;

  @Output()
  eventOne = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.initialValue);
  // eventOne = new EventEmitter<number>();

  ngOnInit() {
    // asapScheduler.schedule(() => this.eventOne.next(this.initialValue));
  }
}
```

**Child HTML**:

```
<p>Child: {{ initialValue }}</p>
```

Have a fun :)

Comment: Thank you!  I will take a look at this and let you know.

Comment: I should probably point out that the app is to be a SPA and the Childs are being loaded by an router action.  So I am presuming that this will still work?

 <router-outlet (updateParent)="updateParentEvent(dbActions)"></router-outlet>